# Test chained ordered methods in minitest

Tags: ruby, minitest

I have a class which implements chained methods that have a natural order, something like:

```
project = proj.new        # initialise object
project = project.create  # create directories for project
project.populate          # populate directories with contents
```

So one could run `proj.new.create.populate`

I'm struggling to test this with `minitest` and feel like I'm tackling the problem incorrectly:

```
class TestProj < Minitest::Test
  def project
    proj.new(dir = "testdir")
  end

  def test_create
    project.create
    assert file.exist?("testdir")
  end

  def test_populate
    project = project.create
    assert file.exist?("testdir")
    project.populate
    # other assertions here
  end
end
```

This seems bad as we have duplicated code and are testing create twice. Should we dispense with `test_create`, but then `test_populate` is testing multiple things? Should we enforce an order of testing and save the results from one test to the next? I feel like I'm missing the "right" solution but am struggling to find it.

Happy to provide more concrete code if required, but I'm trying to simplify to get to the root of the issue.

Comment: I would go with one single test that runs `proj.new(dir = "testdir").create.populate` and checks that everything was created and populated. But if you are obliged to blindly follow guidelines, you are to mock `new` in `create` and mock both `new` and `create` in `populate`, testing exactly one action per a test.

Comment: That's great. I'm interested in both pragmatic and recommended solutions, so this is useful.

Comment: it is hard to tell what way to go without the exact cirumstances. But if the create has a more complex logic, you could always write another function like 'create_project' call the creation and test there, and just call this function in 'test_create', then you can call the same logic again in test_populate.